# How do I get the string from a character array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

**EDIT:** I understand how strings and memory work in C now, this question was due to bad understanding

I have a char buffer which is 64 elements in size. Data is put into it by another function. I want to get all elements of the array which doesn't equal null.

To explain it better, here is an example (pseudocode)

```
char[5] data;
data[0] = 'c';
data[1] = 'a';
data[2] = 't';
data[3]; // = null 
getString(data); // Should return "cat"
```

Comment: A couple of things, a char cannot be null, so I'll assume you mean \0. Do you mean all characters up to the first \0 or all characters in the array which aren't \0? If you mean all that aren't \0, why wouldn't char[4] be included in the getString result?

Comment: All the characters up to the first \0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in C are represented by arrays of characters. These strings are terminated by the null (terminating) character. So if you manually build an array of characters, there is no way how to "get string from a character array", because it is string already.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char data[5];
    data[0] = 'c';
    data[1] = 'a';
    data[2] = 't';
    data[3] = '\0'; // terminating character (avoid using NULL)
    data[4] = 'x';

    printf("%s", data); // output: cat
    return 0;
}
```

Functions like printf "run" through this array till they find terminating character, which is the reason why 'x' won't get to output in my example.

Comment: Thanks, for a C/C++ amateur, from mostly managed code environments, this makes way more sense

Comment: Don't use `NULL` when you mean `'\0'`.

Comment: @LihO NULL is a pointer constant. It does only appear as the same as (int)0, because the C compiler translates the NULL pointer into (int)0 when it must evaluate an pointer as an integer. While the effect looks like the same, there are different concepts involved under the hood. The symbolic constant for (char)0 is NUL (one L). [And this ambiguity is one reason why I don't like C]

Comment: Yes, I see. I edited my answer so that it doesn't guide to using of NULL in this context.

Answer (score 1):

A `char[]` with a null element in it can be used wherever a null-terminated `char*` string is expected, so just use it as-is.

Answer (score 0):

i dont really think you wanna implement a buffer or any need for it like that when u can use string or char arrays.

but here is what u could do if u want to try:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int n,pos=0;
    char ch;    
    cout<<"\nEnter number of characters: ";
    cin>>n;
    char *ptr= new char[n];
    while(pos<n)
    {
    cout<<"\nEnter character: ";
    cin>>ch;
    cout<<"\nEnter position: ";
    cin>>pos;
    ptr[pos]=ch;
    }
    cout<<"\nNumber of Valid characters: ";
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(isalnum(ptr[i])||ispunct(ptr[i]))
        {
            //add other single char function required from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/ according to your use
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout<<count<<endl;
}
```

for single char function required to check consult the page:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/